# How to fix Spring batch partition step which is skipping the slave step?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch which will process date in the database with processed column set to flag N. There is slave step and a master step. Master step is the partition, by this there will be 10 partitioned slave step running concurrently. Now the problem is the partition step started, but it will skipp slave step and output successful right the way.

I already have another similar partition step working correctly. All the set up are the same. Just different step name, repository in  item reader and different logic in itemprocessor etc.

I will provide presudo code

```
//item reader
itemreader(@Value("stepExecutionContext[to]" long to),@Value("stepExecutionContext[from]" long from),@Value("stepExecutionContext[id]") long id){
   logger("partition id: {} process from: {} to: {}",id,to,from);
   //logic, read chunk from to to
}

//item processor and writer, not much to say, just business logic.

//partitioner
public Map<String,ExecutionContext> partition(int grideSize){
    Map<String,ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>();
    int from = 1;
    int range = 10;
    for(i-gridSize) {
        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        context.put("from",from);
        context.put("to",from+range);
        from+=range;
        map.put(partitionkey + "i");
    }
    return map;
}

//partition step
step partitionStep(){
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1.master")
       .partitioner("step1", partitioner)
       .step(step1())
       .gridSize(10)
       .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
       .build();
}

//step1
step step1(){
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        <pojo,pojo> chunk(1)
        .reader(itemreader(null,null,null))
        .processor(itemprocessor())
        .writer(itemwriter())
        .build()
}

//job
job partionJob(){
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionJob")
           .start(partitionStep())
           .build();
}
```

I was expected the logger in item reader will print out the information and  start processing, because this is how it works with another partition step I had.

In my db, the batch_step_execution table shows the 1 master step(partition step) and 10 slave step(partitioned step) which is what I expected, but for slave step, the read count is 0, which should not be because in batch_step_execution_context table, partitioner info shows correctly, like

"id":0,"from":1,"to":10

itemreader should read from 1 to 10 and passed it to itemprocessor and then itemwriter save it.

I wonder what happened, all info is saved in spring batch meta table, why the slave step is still skipped? the map from paritioner isn't empty at all.

Need help.

Comment: Is the reader step-scoped?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine reader, processor and writer are all step scoped

Comment: ok thanks. You should have added this info to the question as this is an important detail. Other than that, I can't see the problem.. Please enable debug log level and post the full log.